# How to get full path names of all opened pdf files (in zathura) - like rofi does

Tags: shell-script, x11, path, zathura, rofi

I am trying to get the full path of every PDF that I have opened in the zathura viewer. I know it is possible, since with `rofi -show window`, I can see the full path.

I have tried running

```
ps -p $(pgrep zathura) -o command
```

however, that only displays part of the name, depending on where I was, when I opened the PDF.

It gets worse, when I use Vimtex, as in that case, it would display something like

```
zathura -x /usr/bin/nvim --headless -c "VimtexInverseSearch %{line} '%{input}'" --synctex-forward 224:1:/Path/to/part.tex main.pdf
```

where main.pdf need not be in the same place as part.tex (this happens if you use \include etc.).

Once gain, rofi does it right!

I could probably write a "convoluted" script that would search recursively in every parent directory of the part.tex file to find the main.pdf file...

Does anyone know how rofi does it?
Or more to the point, how I can do it?

---

I am using

the X11 server

Arch Linux, 6.2.8-arch1-1

GNU bash, Version 5.1.16

Rofi Version: 1.7.5

Zathura version 0.5.2

Thanks all.

Comment: Thanks @RonJohn for the answer. It is nice, but if someone has a faster way of doing it, please, feel free to write it :) Thanks all. - If no better way is suggested, I will mark it as an answer (which it most certainly is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```bash
pids=( $(pgrep zathura) )

for p in "${pids[@]}"; do
  mapfile -d '' -t pdfs < <(
    find "/proc/$p/fd/" -lname '*.pdf' -printf '%l\0')

  [ -n "$pdfs" ] && echo "$p: ${pdfs[@]}"
done
```

This first builds an array (`$pids`) containing the PIDs of all `zathura` processes.

Then, for each PID, it looks in the /proc/PID/fd directory for symlink targets ending in `.pdf` and builds an array (`$pdfs`) of matches.  Both `mapfile` and `find` use NUL as the filename separator, so it will work correctly with any filename (even those containing annoying characters like spaces and newlines and shell meta-characters).

Finally, if the `$pdfs` array isn't empty, it prints the PID and the array.  e.g.

```
3289895: /home/cas/Manuals/X399 Taichi.pdf
3290171: /home/cas/Manuals/Define R5 Web-manual V1.2_151013.pdf
```

NOTE: this is not portable. It only works on Linux (because of /proc/PID/fd - the /proc pseudo-filesystem is specific to linux).

---

Also note: this worked perfectly for me when I searched for `atril` or `qpdfview` processes but failed (due to permissions errors) when I searched for `zathura` processes.

I don't know why, but on my system the `/proc/PID/fd/` directories for atril and qpdfview PIDs were owned by `cas`, but the fd/ directories for zathura PIDs were owned by root and readable only by root.

Weird.  I don't know if this is some weird peculiarity of my system (Debian Sid), or something weird about zathura.

**(Update: turns out that it IS `zathura`.  See [zathura and ownership of files in /proc/PID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741525))**

It does, of course, work if I run `sudo find ...` instead of just `find` in the [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

BTW, unless you already have `sudo` configured to allow your user account to run anything they want as root, I wouldn't recommend configuring it to allow running `find` as root.  `find` has a `-exec` predicate, which can be used to run **anything**.

Instead, write a wrapper script which takes only two arguments:

1. a PID, and
2. a pattern for the `-lname` predicate to match as arguments.

It should check that the PID arg contains only digits and that the /proc/PID directory belongs to the `$SUDO_USER`, and then runs `find` with mostly hard-coded args.  Configure `sudo` to allow that script to be run by your user.

This is how `sudo` is meant to be used, anyway - write very restricted, single purpose wrapper scripts with extremely paranoid input checking that do only one thing. The less done as root, the better.

Here's a very primitive example. It's meant as a minimal **theoretical** example ONLY, **do not use** without careful testing and serious attempts to "break" it.  Seriously, I spent like 2 minutes writing this, it should not be trusted - that is nowhere near enough time to have thought of & countered every possible way that this wrapper script might be subverted.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Arguments:
# $1 PID to examine
# $2 pattern to match -lname (symlink target)
#
# Returns NUL-separated list of matching symlink
# targets found in /proc/$1/fd/

[ "$#" -ne 2 ]       || exit 1  # only two args allowed
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || exit 1  # first arg must be numeric

pdir="/proc/$1"

owner=$(stat --printf '%U' "$pdir")     # GNU stat's printf
[ "$owner" = "$SUDO_USER" ]] || exit 1  # owner must match

find "$pdir/fd/" -lname "$2" -printf '%l\0'
```

If you wanted to be fancy, you could use different exit codes for different error conditions (taking into account that `find` will also have its own exit code if it runs).

Comment: Very nice. And fast. Thank you very much. I have selected it as the answer, as it does everything I wanted.

Comment: Why something so complicated, when the *purpose* of `lsof` is to *list open files*?

Comment: It's not particularly complicated, it's a fairly simple search of the open file-descriptors for zathura processes.  More importantly, it is many thousands of times faster - `lsof` is and always has been excruciatingly slow.  The above is fast, almost instant.    Personally, I'd say that piping grep into grep and then into awk was needlessly complicated, when awk alone is enough (`awk '/evince/ && /pdf$/ { print $NF}'`)

Comment: actually, it could be simplified a bit.  find's `-lname` and `-printf` can be used instead of `-exec` and `readlink`

Comment: @I.P check the updated version, should be even faster (no need to fork readlink and grep for each PID).

Comment: Speed *is* useful.  And thanks for the `awk` tip.

Comment: As a speed comparison, the above code runs in 0.064 seconds on my system.  `lsof` took 48.5 seconds. so, "many thousands of times faster" was a slight exaggeration, actually about 757 times faster...but a program that runs in 0.064 of a second seems "instant" while a program that takes almost a minute seems to take forever.  BTW, my system is not slow.  It's a 16 core threadripper 1950x with 64GB RAM (with 999 processes currently running and 2,223,490 open file descriptors. lsof has to check  all of those, my loop only has to check the fds for about a dozen atril or zathura processes).

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner that works with evince, so should worth with Zathura:

```
lsof 2> /dev/null | grep evince | grep pdf$ | awk '{print $NF}' | uniq
/home/ron/165_dollar_checks.pdf
/home/ron/12_mnt_exh_05_box.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It does indeed. I was aware of lsof, but refrained from using it for a few small reasons: 1 (main reason). it is slow... 2) it needs sudo (not a big issue, I can edit the sudoers file). I am still impressed, how fast rofi does it. I would really like to know, what they are reading. Anyway, it does answer the question, so thank you. It will indeed do the job.