# zathura and ownership of files in /proc/PID

Tags: permissions, proc, zathura

Yesterday, while writing an answer to [How to get full path names of all opened pdf files (in zathura) - like rofi does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741457/how-to-get-full-path-names-of-all-opened-pdf-files-in-zathura-like-rofi-does), I noticed something weird about the ownership of files the /proc/PID/ directory for zathura processes - **most of them are owned by root instead of the user (cas) I ran zathura as**.

For example:

```
$ cd ~/Manuals
$ zathura X399\ Taichi.pdf &
[1] 4055396

$ ls -lF /proc/4055396/fd
ls: cannot open directory '/proc/4055396/fd': Permission denied
$ ls -lFd /proc/4055396/fd
dr-x------ 2 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 /proc/4055396/fd/
```

huh? why is that owned by `root`?  I ran it as `cas`.

Most, but not all of the files/dirs in /proc/4055396 are owned by root:

```
$ ls -lF /proc/4055396
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/4055396/cwd': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/4055396/root': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/4055396/exe': Permission denied
total 0
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 arch_status
dr-xr-xr-x  2 cas  cas  0 Mar 31 13:04 attr/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 autogroup
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 auxv
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 cgroup
--w-------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 clear_refs
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:02 cmdline
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 comm
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 coredump_filter
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 cpu_resctrl_groups
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 cwd
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 environ
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:02 exe
dr-x------  2 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 fd/
dr-xr-xr-x  2 cas  cas  0 Mar 31 13:04 fdinfo/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 gid_map
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 io
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 ksm_merging_pages
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 ksm_stat
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 limits
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 loginuid
dr-x------  2 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 map_files/
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 maps
-rw-------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 mem
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 mountinfo
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 mounts
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 mountstats
dr-xr-xr-x 57 cas  cas  0 Mar 31 13:04 net/
dr-x--x--x  2 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 ns/
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 numa_maps
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 oom_adj
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 oom_score
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 oom_score_adj
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 pagemap
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 patch_state
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 personality
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 projid_map
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 root
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 sched
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 schedstat
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 sessionid
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 setgroups
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 smaps
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 smaps_rollup
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 stack
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:02 stat
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 statm
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 status
-r--------  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 syscall
dr-xr-xr-x  6 cas  cas  0 Mar 31 13:04 task/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 timens_offsets
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 timers
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 timerslack_ns
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 uid_map
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Mar 31 13:04 wchan
```

`zathura` is NOT setuid root:

```
$ type -p zathura
/usr/bin/zathura

$ ls -l /usr/bin/zathura
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 305456 Nov 28 03:34 /usr/bin/zathura
```

It is version 0.5.2, and the package was last upgraded on November 28 last year:

```
$ zathura --version
zathura 0.5.2
girara 0.3.7 (runtime: 0.4.0)
(plugin) cb (0.1.10) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libcb.so)
(plugin) pdf-poppler (0.3.1) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libpdf-poppler.so)
(plugin) ps (0.2.7) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libps.so)
(plugin) djvu (0.2.9) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libdjvu.so)

$ dpkg -l zathura
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=============================================
ii  zathura        0.5.2-1      amd64        document viewer with a minimalistic interface

$ ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives/zathura_0.5.2-1_amd64.deb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175712 Nov 28 04:41 /var/cache/apt/archives/zathura_0.5.2-1_amd64.deb
```

If I use `qpdfview`, `atril`, or `okular` instead of `zathura`, the permissions are fine:

```
$ qpdfview X399\ Taichi.pdf 
$ pgrep qpdfview
4071588 qpdfview X399 Taichi.pdf
$ ls -lFd /proc/4071588/fd
dr-x------ 2 cas cas 0 Mar 31 13:16 /proc/4071588/fd/

$ atril X399\ Taichi.pdf &
[1] 4080297
$ ls -lFd /proc/4080297/fd
dr-x------ 2 cas cas 0 Mar 31 13:20 /proc/4080297/fd/

$ okular X399\ Taichi.pdf &
[1] 4081710
$ ls -lFd /proc/4081710/fd
dr-x------ 2 cas cas 0 Mar 31 13:21 /proc/4081710/fd/
```

All of the above were run from the same instance of bash, same environment, same everything. Not in a VM or container, or anything "unusual".

So, what is up with `zathura`?  Is it zathura? or is it some weird namespaces related behaviour by systemd or cgroups or something like that?

The system is running Debian sid (updated yesterday), with kernel `Linux hex 6.1.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.15-1 (2023-03-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. The last reboot was 14 days ago when I upgraded the kernel, has been running fine since then.

---

NOTE: I vaguely recall that when I was working on my answer yesterday, I saw the same root ownership thing for ONE of the instances of running `atril`, but I can't replicate that now. I may have mis-remembered this, it was very late at night (> 3am) and I was tired.

`zathura`, however, consistently has root-owned stuff in /proc/PID/ - every time I run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zathura applies a number of settings to protect itself and the user from potentially malicious content; among other things, it disables dumping using [`pctrl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, SUID_DUMP_DISABLE`)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html), which changes the ownership of files inside [`/proc/PID`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> The files inside each `/proc/[pid]` directory are normally
> owned by the effective user and effective group ID of the
> process.  However, as a security measure, the ownership is
> made `root:root` if the process's "dumpable" attribute is
> set to a value other than 1.

Despite the constant’s name, this applies to non-suid binaries too.

There’s [an exception to this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.9/source/fs/proc/base.c#L1848): directories which are world-readable and world-executable (currently the pid directory itself, along with `attr`, `fdinfo`, `net` and `task`) keep the process’ effective uid and gid. This is done so that callers can still `stat` the `/proc/PID` directory.

Comment: that seems almost certainly to be the cause.  I've used zathura on and off for many years (although i mostly use qpdfview for PDFs...it's been great until recently when suddenly its font rendering turned to shit), and this has never had any impact on what i'm doing until now - guess you have to be doing something unusual like directly examining the process's file descriptors.

Comment: I guess there must be some good reason for preventing the PIDs owner from seeing what file descriptors it has open, some exploitable case.     Interestingly, I just noticed that while zathura's /proc/PID/fd is root:root 700, its /proc/PID/fdinfo is cas:cas 755 but running `ls -lF` on that directory gets `ls: cannot open directory '/proc/4090889/fdinfo/': Permission denied` (the files in it are root:root 444 when listed with `sudo ls`).   755 on the dir should let me list the directory, shouldn't it?

Comment: I was wondering about that, on my system `zathura`’s `fdinfo` is `root:root`. 755 should indeed let you list the directory but perhaps `procfs` is returning an error anyway.